# symfony2 FOSUserBundle data from the custom field do not write to the database

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I I read the documentation about overwrite a lot of times and I still don't know why this code doesn't work. Custom field - package works but data doesn't save in database.

Company\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php

```
namespace Company\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('phoneNumber', 'text', array('label' => 'Numer telefonu(opcjonalnie)', 'required' => false))
            ->add('package', 'integer', array('label' => 'Pakiet', 'required' => false ));

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Registration controller is default.

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register m-signup--form">
        <h2>Zarejestruj się</h2>
        <ul class="errorLog">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_email">Email</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_username">Login</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phoneNumber">Numer telefonu <span>(opcjonalnie)</span></label>
            {{ form_widget(form.phoneNumber) }}
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_package">Pakiet</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.package) }}
        </div>
            <span>{{ form_widget(form) }}</span>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="font-weight: bold;" value="Zarejestruj się" />
    </form>
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

Company\UserBundle\Entity\User.php

```
namespace Company\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="phone_number", nullable = true)
     */
    public $phoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="package")
     */
    public $package;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPackage()
    {
        return $this->package;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $package
     */
    public function setPackage($package)
    {
        $this->package = $package;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $phoneNumber
     */
    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
    }

     ...
```

app\config\config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Company\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
        form:
            type: company_user_registration
```

Company\UserBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

```
services:
    company_user.password_resetting:
        class: Company\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationCompleteListener
        arguments: [@router, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @templating]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
    company_user.registration.form.type:
            class: Company\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
            tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: company_user_registration }
```

RegistrationController.php

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

            $user = $userManager->createUser();
            $user->setEnabled(true);

            $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

            if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
                return $event->getResponse();
            }

            $form = $formFactory->createForm();
            $form->setData($user);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
                $form->bind($request);

                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                    $userManager->updateUser($user);

                    if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {

                        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                    }

                    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                    return $response;
                } else {
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    $errors = array();
                    $errors = $this->getErrorMessages($form);
                    $errors["status"] = "error";
                    return new Response(json_encode($errors));
                }
            }
            return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.' . $this->getEngine(), array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));

        }
        //Listowanie błędów
        private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
            $errors = array();
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
                $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
                $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

                foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
                    $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
                }

                $errors[$key] = $template;
            }
            if ($form->count()) {
                foreach ($form as $child) {
                    if (!$child->isValid()) {
                        $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $errors;
        }

        /**
         * Tell the user to check his email provider
         */
        public function checkEmailAction()
        {

            $email = $this->container->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
            $this->container->get('session')->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
            $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);

            if (null === $user) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with email "%s" does not exist', $email));
            }

            return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail.html.' . $this->getEngine(), array(
                'user' => $user,
            ));
        }

        /**
         * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user
         */
        public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
        {
            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

            $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

            if (null === $user) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
            }

            /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
            $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

            $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
            $user->setEnabled(true);

            $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        /**
         * Tell the user his account is now confirmed
         */
        public function confirmedAction()
        {
            $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
            }

            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('static_user_add_first');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            return $response;
        }

        protected function getEngine()
        {
            return $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you extend `UserEntity`? You have to define `package` field (also in your orm file definition), and seter/geter fot it.

Comment: Please show me part of your `config.yml` related to `fos_user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you properly [configure](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) FOSUser (config.yml) ?

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: YourApp\UserBundle\Entity\User #path to your custom User entity
```

Moreover, does your form contains the following methods ?

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'yourapp_user_registration';
}
```

The way your are building your form gives me hints about your misconfiguration. You are trying to add fields that are already existing within the registration form FOSUser provides.

Your buildForm method would be more likely to look like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('phoneNumber', 'text',  array('label' => 'Numer telefonu(opcjonalnie)', 'required' => false))
        ->add('package', 'text', array('label' => 'Pakiet', 'required' => false ));
}
```

To make this work, you'll have to make the form a Service:

```
services:
    yourapp_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Path\To\Your\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: yourapp_user_registration }
```

And link your config.yml to the said service:

```
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            type: yourapp_user_registration
```

Comment: I did as you said but sill nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "still nothing" ? No error? Did you clear the cache ? Did you check your services exist within the app ? Did your form validate ?

Comment: No error. I cleared the cache. Form is validated. PhoneNumber field works but package field no and I don't know why.

Comment: I see your package attribute is a integer and you are building your input as a text. What do you give as value in your input ? Can we see your controller ? (Or services where your form is processed)

Comment: I use this controller. I've changed type to integer and still doesn't save.

Comment: Is this the FOS controller ? My question was more like to ask you if you were using any business code which interacts with the form. This one is the fos user isn't it ?

Comment: No I haven't got any business code for this, It's default fos controller. Yes, It's fos user. Maybe I don't understand this register process because I write all in accordance with the documentation. I'll be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray!! I've finally found!
The problem was in onRegistrationSuccess function in Listener. Previous programmer call there setPackage function with static value. When I removed it all began to work.

Grégory Elhaimer thank you very much for your engagement and help. You're great!

Comment: Haha, static sutff are often miss used and then lead to nightmares. Glad you've find it out :p